# How to utilize API call to overwrite/update Google Sheet?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

My current API request will post a new Google Sheet every time it runs, but I just want it to either overwrite the existing sheet or just update it with new data.

I've tried using different request methods, but it's not doing what I am looking to do.

Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart

Request Method: POST

Content Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"

Request Body:
        --foo_bar_baz
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

```
{
  "name": "<var_my_google_sheet_name>",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8

<var_query_results>
--foo_bar_baz--
```

Hoping to have it either overwrite the existing table over and over with updated data, or to just append new data to the existing table.

Comment: From your request body, it seems that a CSV data is uploaded to Google Drive by converting to Spreadsheet. When you want to update the Spreadsheet, I recommend to use Sheets API. You can update the Spreadsheet by Sheets API. For example, how about using the method of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate In this case, you can append the values to the existing Spreadsheet.

Comment: So, currently I have a process that takes my saved GBQ table and posts it to a Google Sheet. But if this process runs every day, it'll be a new sheet with almost the same data (each day will basically have x amount of new rows pertaining the the new day). Rather than a new sheet being created, I just want to overwrite the existing one daily. Or, I can change my query to just pull one day's data and then have the API append this data daily. Either one is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Forewarning, I'm not too skilled with APIs so this is fairly new to me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As another way, if you want to replace the existing Spreadsheet by new Spreadsheet without changing the file ID, how about using the method of Files: update of Drive API? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

Comment: Probable a simple question, but how do I find out the file ID? Once I have it, would I basically do https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId/uploadType=multipart

Comment: You can retrieve file IDs using the method of files.list of Drive API. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: The file ID is the same as the spreadsheet ID that gets created. It is sent back in the response to the create / upload request.

Comment: So I have the file ID, do I change the request URl to this? https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1GOs_88sTGmaBo1iX5Ivj9byINMLgNvycYjgCKz9BX_Y?uploadType=multipart